# Some Google Tag Manager form submission events not showing up in Google Analytics Real-time

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, form-submit

I implemented form submission tracking with Google Tag Manager on my website. Whenever a form is submitted I got an email. It seems that maybe out of every 3 form submissions Google Analytics only records ~one event.

I tried to debug the issue using the preview mode in GTM. It seems that when I submit the form (making sure that the submitted form goes to a different browser window) I can see in the preview window that my form submission tag was fired, and I can also see the event in Google Analytics Real-Time / Events, so everything looks okay.

However if I leave the preview mode and do the same, I cannot see the form submission event any more in GA real-time.

My questions: 
1. why do I not see the form submission when I leave the preview mode?
2. what would be the best way to debug the whole process to make sure that I will get all the form submission events in the future?

Thanks a lot for any hints?
W.

Comment: Did you publish your changes? If they're unpublished, they won't appear when not in preview mode

Comment: Now after publishing my latest version, it seems to be working, thanks! Let's hope that this somehow also solves my other problem and I will get all the events. Thanks!